# How to set a timer inside the get request of an APIView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build a timer inside a get method in a DRF View. I have created the timer method inside the GameViewController class and what I am trying to achieve is that a every minute (5 times in a row) a resource object is shown to the user through the get request and a game round object is created. My View works at the moment, however the timer doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I know this isn't exactly how things are done in django but this is how I need to do it for my game API for game logic purposes.

How can I make the timer work? Do I need to use something like request.time or such?

Thanks in advance.

**views.py**

```
class GameView(APIView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
...
round_number = gametype.rounds
        # time = controller.timer()

        now = datetime.now()
        now_plus_1 = now + timedelta(minutes=1)

        while round_number != 0:
            while now < now_plus_1:

                random_resource = Resource.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
                resource_serializer = ResourceSerializer(random_resource)

                gameround = Gameround.objects.create(
                    id=controller.generate_random_id(Gameround),
                    user_id=current_user_id,
                    gamesession=gamesession,
                    created=datetime.now(),
                    score=current_score
                )
                gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround)
                round_number -= 1

                return Response({# 'gametype': gametype_serializer.data,
                                 'resource': resource_serializer.data,
                                 'gameround': gameround_serializer.data
                                 })
```

Comment: I think some way to do it is by using cron job, or if you want it real time you have to use websockets (with channels in django)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to jump quickly into this - use huey https://github.com/coleifer/huey

You will need to install Redis as a backend of your queue. It's not complicated.

Huey can run your code by cron, delays or something else complicated:

```
from huey import RedisHuey, crontab

huey = RedisHuey('my-app', host='redis.myapp.com')

@huey.task()
def add_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b

@huey.task(retries=2, retry_delay=60)
def flaky_task(url):
    # This task might fail, in which case it will be retried up to 2 times
    # with a delay of 60s between retries.
    return this_might_fail(url)

@huey.periodic_task(crontab(minute='0', hour='3'))
def nightly_backup():
    sync_all_data()
```

Hyue has the Django extentions https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html#django

As for me, this was the fastest way to achieve the same tasks and this has been working in production for ~1 year without my support.

Comment: I am already working with Redis. So if I understand you correctly, I would just write these methods inside my views.py file?

Comment: So it works like async tasks: you are writing your tasks and then you are simply scheduling a needed task(s) with the needed schedule. It works perfectly with Django and ORM. More info in the Django section of the docs.